# Azure Devops pipeline - C++ - Whitesource Bolt

Tags: c++11, security, azure-pipelines

I have a project, written in C++, and built into docker image. I used some opensource libraries (nlohmann json, gtest, cpr etc) in my project.

Now, i was trying to find open source vulnerabilities using Whitesource Bolt. I added the extension to Azure pipeline task.

I wonder, how Whitesource Bolt identifies vulnerabilities in those opensource modules. i read that, they will create a digital signature and compare it with their database.

But, can anyone describe how they are creating digital signature, or how they are identifying open source modules in our code ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Every open source modules have their special digital signature. Whitesource Bolt calculates these digital signatures to find open source modules.

Comment: Thanks. But My project is written in C++, and using Cmake, I’m using some opensource libraries (nlohmann json, cpr etc). I’ve pre downloaded all these libraries, made static libraries and attached it with my repo. So Whitesource is unable to identify these libraries. So is there any way to mentions these libraries and versions anywhere, like a ‘pom.xml’ so tha Whitesource could identify it.